# MenuApp in Swift 4 to Run on Login for High Sierra?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift4

My app is a menu app that sits in the menu extras running in the background, and I'm trying to make it to run on login. What's the latest recommended practice to achieve this for High Sierra using Swift 4?

According to [Designing Daemons and Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/DesigningDaemons.html), there are four different background processes on MacOS.

Since I would want my app to run upon user login, I guess it's going to be either login item or launch agent. However, for Login Item, it seems there are [two ways to implement](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html) Using the Service Management Framework or a Shared File List.

I first attempted to use Shared File List, based from this [example](https://gist.github.com/plapier/f8e1dde1b1624dfbb3e4) from github. However, Xcode throws bunch of deprecated warnings and errors indicating it doesn't support in Swift 4 and latest MacOS anymore.

Then I got it to work using using SMLoginItemSetEnabled from [this guide](https://theswiftdev.com/2017/10/27/how-to-launch-a-macos-app-at-login/). However, using this method, my app doesn't show up inn the system preferences under the login items.

Is Shared File List method is completely out of option for Swift 4 and High Sierra?

What about launch agent? I couldn't find much guide on making an App as a launch agent using Swift. I would appreciate if someone could share some code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a launch agent. Login items are soooo 2010 ;).

There's really no API for creating a launch agent (or other `launchd` services). The steps are, basically:

1. create and write the appropriate `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.your.agent.plist` file
2. execute `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.your.agent.plist`

(where *501* and *com.your.agent* are the user's UID and your launchd identifier)

The second step is somewhat optional; the system will see your `.plist` file and start the agent automatically the next time the system restarts. So you can kick start it by just manually launching it the first time. But if you want it to be immediately registered with `launchd` (so it will automatically get restarted if quit, for example), then I know of no other way than to run `launchctl` once to register it. (Similarly, you'll need to run `launchctl bootout ...` to shut it down when it's time to uninstall it.[1])

The details of the `.plist` file can be found in `man launchd.plist`, but here's a simple example of a `LSUIElement` app called "Menu" that runs in the background whenever the user is logged into to a GUI session:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <dict>
        <key>SuccessfulExit</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.my.menu</string>
    <key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
    <string>Aqua</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Applications/Menu.app/Contents/MacOS/Menu</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

To create the `.plist`, all you have to do is populate a property list dictionary with these values and call `dictionary.write(to:atomically:)` to write it where it belongs.

Launch agents are regular user processes so none of this requires any special privileges, although I'm not sure about writing to `~/Library/LaunchAgents` from a sandboxed app.

Since the user doesn't normally fiddle with `~/Library/LaunchAgents`or `launchctl` your application will need to provide a UI for installing and uninstalling the agent. For a status menu item app, this is usually as simple as a preferences checkbox to "Show in Menubar".

[1] `bootstrap` and `bootout` were added in 10.11. If you have to support earlier versions of macOS there are workarounds.

Comment: Thanks @JamesBucanek! Basically I just need to copy the plist file to ~/Library/LaunchAgents, and it'll load next time it reboots. I don't even need to bother with launchctl?

Comment: Correct. If you can wait for a reboot you don't need to do anything more than copy the property list to the proper location. `launchd` scans all of its configuration directories (`~/Library/LaunchAgents`, `/Library/LaunchAgents`, `/Library/LaunchDeamons`, ...) when it starts up and registers everything it finds. The same applies to removing it.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way especially for a sandboxed app is the Service Management Framework (`SMLoginItemSetEnabled`) and a helper executable located in `./Contents/Library/LoginItems`

Of course the application does not appear in Login Items of System Preferences because the behavior is supposed to be controlled in the app itself.