# Launching non-sandboxed Swift app at login -- best practice

Tags: swift, macos

I've developed a Mac status-menu app which can't be sandboxed, because it creates a virtual drive; it's installed alongside a Finder rightclick-menu extension, which does conform to sandboxing rules.  At this point (after manual install) the right-click launches smoothly on login, but the application doesn't.

In recent versions of MacOS the previous methods for adding an app to login items (involving LSSharedFile) have been deprecated. The examples I've found since then involving SMLoginItemSetEnabled or launch agents (e.g. [MenuApp in Swift 4 to Run on Login for High Sierra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48884987/menuapp-in-swift-4-to-run-on-login-for-high-sierra)) all seem to involve sandboxing.  Is there a best practice for running an un-sandboxed app at login on OS X 10.11+ -- either in code or at installation time?

I'm thinking about using a launch agent, as described above; can all these steps be done at install time with administrator privileges, even without sandboxing?  And if so, what would I need to do to automate uninstallation as well?